# HEAD HTTP requests in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Rails 3 currently routes a HEAD request to the matching GET route. There is a head? method on the request, but in returns false and the request acts like a get request.  Can I detect if the request is a HEAD request?

Reasoning: I get that a HEAD request should return the EXACT same headers as the get, so Rails wants to perform the full GET and then shave off the body. However, I can conform to this request without issuing the same DB calls, etc that the GET would. Does this make sense?

Comment: You may need to post some relevant code. The head? method should return true for HEAD requests (http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Request.html#method-i-head-3F)

Answer (score 4):

I had this exact issue. It turns out that enabling caching causes this. Turn caching off in your environment and #head? will work as expected.

The issue is that Rack::Cache turns HEAD requests into GET requests so they can be cached. This is arguably the correct behavior, but it interfered with my application.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the request.head? method to find out if it's a HEAD request:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Request.html#method-i-head-3F

Once you've determined that it is, you can also use the controller's head() method instead of the typical render:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-head-to-build-header-only-responses

So I'd simply check request.head? before bothering with the database activities.  Then use

```
head :ok, :custom_header => 'value'
```

Comment: So, here's a gist with some [more info](https://gist.github.com/2594991) You can see that the HEAD is routed to the GET my Rails, at which point the request says it's a GET. I tried the head?, but can't get it to indicate that it is a HEAD request.

Answer (score 1):

```
def index
  if request.head?
    head :created
  else
    Rails.logger.info "Derp #{request.method}"
  end
end
```

Hmm. The above controller method works like I'd expect on Ruby v1.9.3-p194 and Rails v3.2.3; 201's w/o response body for the HEAD requests and 200's w/ for the GET's.

Comment: I'm on 1.9.2 and Rails 3.1.4...I am fully prepared to be doing something wrong. I'll have to investigate further...Thanks.

Comment: So, I think the real answer is that rails forces the HEAD request thru the same action that handles GET is b/c it has to generate the ETag. If HEAD did something different, it would (likely) break client-side caching. As such, the exact calls have to be issued....

I don't like that I can't really use head? to know it's a HEAD request, but I (think I) understand the reasoning.