# Issue while processing HEAD and GET request in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Currently we are facing issue for processing the HEAD and GET request. Let me explain the detailed scenario

We have integrated inbound and outbound SMS facility in our application.

But from last 2-3 months we are getting 2-3 times GET request from the SMS service provider and it is affecting on our system.

After long discussion with SMS service provider, they are saying *"Both Head and Get requests are handled similarly from your end"*

I also referred [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10439023/head-http-requests-in-rails-3). You can find respective logs at [this link](http://pastebin.com/7HhpsCRi)

So can any one suggest how to resolve this issue.

**EDIT**
After research we found that we are getting all the parameters in both HEAD and GET request because of this server is processing it.

Comment: Try something like this:
match 'user/show' => 'users#show', :via => [:get, :head]

Comment: @i-am-simple-user What is the issue ? There are more GET requests than usual ? What problem does that cause ?

Comment: @ThongKuah basically I am using heroku and it is treating HEAD request as a GET. Though I get the HEAD it is taking GET and also in logs it is showing me GET only not HEAD

Comment: Can you give a sample from the heroku logs? Showing the lines from both the router and the worker?

Comment: @bbozo you can find the logs here [http://pastebin.com/7HhpsCRi]

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem might be the [ActionDispatch::Head](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.8/classes/ActionDispatch/Head.html) middleware.
Part of that is following code:

```
def call(env)
  if env["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "HEAD"
    env["REQUEST_METHOD"] = "GET"
    env["rack.methodoverride.original_method"] = "HEAD"
    status, headers, _ = @app.call(env)
    [status, headers, []]
  else
    @app.call(env)
  end
end
```

So essentially the middleware changes the request-method before the router even gets the request.
If you want your router to handle the difference between HEAD and GET requests, you can remove the middleware by adding

```
config.middleware.delete "ActionDispatch::Head"
```

to your application.rb

Otherwise you should be able to access that variable in your controller like this:

```
if request.env["rack.methodoverride.original_method"]=='HEAD'
  #do head processing here
  head :ok, :additional_header => 'value'
else
  #do get processing here
end
```

If you worry about performance, I suggest writing your own middleware to handle these requests. Railscasts has a few [good](http://railscasts.com/episodes/151-rack-middleware) tutorials on [this](http://railscasts.com/episodes/399-autocomplete-search-terms).

Also note, that other middlewares, like Rack::Cache might interfere in this process as well. So you should insert your middleware on top:

```
config.middleware.insert_before 0, "YourMiddleware"
```

Comment: tried your solution but still facing the same issue

Comment: Which solution have you tried? If you tried the middleware, and it was on top of the chain, that might mean your server (nginx, unicorn, etc.) might convert the HEAD to a GET request. Also: have you doing a head request with curl (`curl -i -X HEAD [url]`) ?  Maybe the issue is on client side.

Answer (score 0):

I would just implement my own :head response as the example in https://stackoverflow.com/a/10453525/5446866

```
if request.head?
 head :ok # or whatever
else
 # your other complex stuff here
end
```

You could also add a route specific to head request. for example

```
match '/validate_messages/sms' => 'validate_messages#noop', via: :head
```

and then in your controller

```
def noop
  head :ok
end
```

basically, you have to implement what you want to do with `HEAD` request otherwise it will go ahead and use your `GET` handler

Hope that helps

Comment: isn't this what you wanted? i.e respond to `head` and `get` requests differently?

Comment: yes, basically it should not process the HEAD request

Comment: that noop will basically do nothing but return a 200 status